# How to get the length of an array without ngRepeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-http

I'm trying to count the items in an array without using `ng-repeat` (I don't really need it, i just want to print out the sum).

This is what I've done so far: http://codepen.io/nickimola/pen/zqwOMN?editors=1010

**HTML**:

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <h1>Test</h1> 
    <div ng-cloak>{{totalErrors()}}</div>
</body>
```

**Javascript:**

```
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', '$timeout', function($scope) {

    $scope.tiles= {
            'data':[
                {'issues':[
                    {'name':'Test','errors':[
                        {'id':1,'level':2},
                        {'id':3,'level':1},
                        {'id':5,'level':1},
                        {'id':5,'level':1}
                    ]},
                    {'name':'Test','errors':[
                        {'id':1,'level':2,'details':{}},
                        {'id':5,'level':1}
                    ]}
                ]}
            ]}
  $scope.totalErrors = function() {
  if ($scope.tiles){
        var topLevel = $scope.tiles.data
        console.log (topLevel);
   return topLevel[0].issues.map(function(o) {
            return o.errors.length
          })
          .reduce(function (prev, curr){
            return prev + curr
          })
    }
    }
}]);
```

This code works on codepen, but on my app I get this error:

> Cannot read property '0' of undefined

and if I debug it, topLevel is undefined when the functions is called.

I think it is related to the loading of the data, as on my app I have a service that looks like this:

```
angular.module('services', ['ngResource']).factory('tilesData', [
  '$http', '$stateParams', function($http, $stateParams) {
    var tilesData;
    tilesData = function(myData) {
      if (myData) {
        return this.setData(myData);
      }
    };
    tilesData.prototype = {
      setData: function(myData) {
        return angular.extend(this, myData);
      },
      load: function(id) {
        var scope;
        scope = this;
        return $http.get('default-system.json').success(function(myData) {
          return scope.setData(myData.data);
        }).error(function(err) {
          return console.error(err);
        });
      }
    };
    return tilesData;
  }
]);
```

and I load the data like this in my controller:

```
angular.module('myController', ['services', 'ionic']).controller('uiSettings', [
  '$scope', '$ionicPopup', '$ionicModal', 'tilesData', function($scope, $ionicPopup, $ionicModal, tilesData) {
    $scope.tiles = new tilesData();
    $scope.tiles.load();
    $scope.totalErrors = function() {
      debugger;
      var topLevel;
      topLevel = $scope.tiles.data;
      console.log(topLevel);
      return topLevel[0].issues.map(function(o) {
        return o.errors.length;
      }).reduce(function(prev, curr) {
        return prev + curr;
      });
    };
  }
]);
```

but I don't know what to do to solve this issue. Any help will be really appreciated. Thanks a lot

Comment: In the service, load function: `return scope.setData(myData);`.

Comment: Looks like you fixed, it....going to codepen shows 6 in the page.

Comment: Please consider to post your entire controller code from your app.

Comment: @RaulA. codepen works as data is already there. in my app it is loaded over $http and it seams like it is still not there when i need it

Comment: @ShaohaoLin please check my edited question

Comment: Are you able to get the data? Can you `console.log($scope.tiles.data;)`?

Comment: You're using $http.get in your load function, which is asynchronous. You will need to return a promise from your load function, and use the same .then() notation that you've used as a response from the $http.get in your controller.  have a look here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q

Comment: yes data is there as i'm using a lot of repeater in the html and everything looks fine. I cannot really print tiles.data as the .data part is in my service: return $http.get('default-system.json').success(function(myData) {
          return scope.setData(myData.data);

Comment: Is `topLevel` an object or an array? What happene if you try to `console.log(topLevel[0]);`?

Comment: in my app is undefined, so i don't really know, but on the codepen is an array, you can see it as well. But that code works. I think @Jingo is right and I probably need to use promises, but i don't really know how and some help will be really appreciated

Comment: I feel like you can do `return topLevel.issues.map(function(o) { ...} ` without the `0`.

Comment: I believe it is more about data structure problem because you had told me you are able to do `console.log($scope.tiles.data);`. Therefore, it wouldn't be an asynchronous problem. It means you get the data from service to controller.

Comment: That is exactly what i'm doing. I'm loading data from the service to the controller in an asyncronous way. I need ot use promises and that's the thing that i don't really know how to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$http.get()` method is **asynchronous**, so you can handle this in your controller with a **callback or a promise**. I have an example using a promise here.

I've made an example pen that passes back the sample data you use above asynchronously.This mocks the `$http.get` call you make.

I have handled the async call in the controller in a slightly different way to what you had done, but this way it works with the `.then()` pattern that promises use. This should give you an example of how you can handle the async code in your controller.

Note as well that my service is in the same module as my controller. This shouldn't matter and the way you've done it, injecting your factory module into your main module is fine.

```
angular.module('myApp', [])

//Define your controller
.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope','myFactory', function($scope,myFactory) {        
    //call async function from service, with .then pattern:
    myFactory.myFunction().then(
    function(data){
        // Call function that does your map reduce
        $scope.totalErrors = setTotalErrors();
    },
    function(error){
        console.log(error);
    });

  function setTotalErrors () {
    if ($scope.tiles){
                var topLevel = $scope.tiles.data
                console.log (topLevel);
     return topLevel[0].issues.map(function(o) {
                        return o.errors.length
                    })
                    .reduce(function (prev, curr){
                        return prev + curr
                    });
        }
 }
}])
.factory('myFactory', ['$timeout','$q',function($timeout,$q){
return {
    myFunction : myFunction
};

function myFunction(){
    //Create deferred object with $q.
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    //mock an async call with a timeout
    $timeout(function(){
        //resolve the promise with the sample data
        deferred.resolve(
            {'data':[
            {'issues':[
                {'name':'Test','errors':[
                    {'id':1,'level':2},
                    {'id':3,'level':1},
                    {'id':5,'level':1},
                    {'id':5,'level':1}
                ]},
                {'name':'Test','errors':[
                    {'id':1,'level':2,'details':{}},
                    {'id':5,'level':1}
                ]}
            ]}
        ]})
    },200);

    //return promise object.
    return deferred.promise;
}
}]);
```

Have a look : [Link to codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eZWYoM?editors=1010)

Also, have a read of the $q documentation: [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q)

Comment: You code seams to work, but I typed in the wrong json file and now i'm a bit stuck again, can you please check this codepen please? i need to iterate trough a list of arrays so topLevel[0].issues.map wont really work: http://codepen.io/nickimola/pen/zqwOMN?editors=1010

Comment: You'll need to iterate through both the arrays and the the arrays of errors within the arrays for this to work. You could call something similar to your map and reduce calls within your top level map calls

Comment: i did it this way: http://codepen.io/nickimola/pen/zqwOMN?editors=0010 but i get "cannot read property '0' of null, while in the console the value is correct

Comment: This pen shows how you can cycle through each object to get the errors: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BKRRJq?editors=1010 ... In your one, you were only cycling through your top level objects.